# On a statistic for permutations

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, terminology, permutations

Given a permutation $\pi$ we can write $\pi=s_{i_1} ... s_{i_l}$ as a product of simple transpositions $s_i=(i,i+1)$ in a minimal way.

> Question 1: Is there an "official" name for the permutation statistic given by the cardinality of the set $\{i_1,...,i_l \}$ ? (such as Coxeter length seems to be the official name for $l$)

See http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000019 for this statistic.

> Question 2: Is there a reference that the generating function for this permutation statistic restricted to 321-avoiding permutations is given by Catalan's triangle: http://oeis.org/A009766 ?

Comment: Q1: I have seen $\{i_1,\dots,i_l\}$ being called **support** of $\pi$ as it is independent of the chosen word the Matsumoto's property that all reduced expressions are connected by braid relations.

Comment: Just looking at St000019: what is wrong with **cardinality of support** ?

Comment: @ChristianStump I guess "Support cardinality" might be a good name for this statistic, but maybe there is already a name for this used in some textbook/article that might be even shorter.

Comment: The support of a permutation can also mean the set of all of its non-fixed points. That is a different set.

Comment: I think Bridget Tenner is someone worth asking about this (or at least looking into her papers).

Comment: Not directly related but in the case of 312-avoiding permutation, the map in Section 3 of the Bandlow-Killpatrick paper might be useful. https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v8i1r40/pdf

Answer (score 2):

For Q1, the sequence corresponding to [Stat19](http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000019) is given in [A263484](http://oeis.org/A263484) and comes from a 2005 article by Richard Stanley (developing ideas from Comtet) on connectivity sets, connectedness, cut points, etc.

It may not have a standard name because it is the reflection of the decomposition/block number [Stat56](http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000056), i.e., for $\pi \in S_n$, $\text{Stat19}(\pi) = n - \text{Stat56}(\pi)$.  See [A059438](http://oeis.org/A059438).  Another related statistic is global ascents [Stat234](http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000234).

For Q2, the connection between block numbers of 321-avoiding permutations and Catalan's triangle was established by Adin, Bagno, and Roichman, [arXiv 1611.06979](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06979), later *J. Algebraic Combinatorics*.  The related [abstract](https://pp2017.github.io/assets/pdf/abstracts/talks/eli_bagno.pdf) for Bagno's talk at the Permutation Patterns 2017 conference is more expository.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, *support* doesn't appear to be an appropriate word, as in the context of permutations it is normally used for the set of non-fixed points. In general, a mathematical *support* means as an assistance to the main act.

To try to define the term, we can first define the process that arrives at the statistic:

Let $T_n$ be the set of all non-trivial simple transpositions on a set of size $n$, say $S$.

Let $\pi$ be a permutation of $S$, and let $$\;_\pi T_n=\left\{\{t_1,\dots t_k\}\in T_n^k:\pi\prod_\limits{i=1}^k t_i=S\right\}$$

i.e. $\;_\pi T_n$ is the set of sets of simple transpositions that take $\pi$ to the identity $S$.

Define:

$$\;_\pi U_n(t\in \;_\pi T_n) =\{u:u\in t\}$$

as the set of unique elements of a set $t$, and

$$_\pi U_n=\bigcup_t \;_\pi U_n(t)$$

as the set of sets that contain the unique elements of simple transposition sets from $\;_\pi T_n$.

Define $\;_\pi V_n=\{|v|:v\in \;_\pi U_n\}$ and then the statistic we want is $\min(\;_\pi V_n)$.

So, **minimum cardinality of the identifying simple transposition sets for a permutation $\pi$**, or perhaps, **the minimum number of simple transpositions needed to return $\pi$ to $S$**.

The actual statistic can be easily calculated by creating an array of $n-1$, and ticking every cell that is crossed by returning an element in a straight path to it's original position, and counting the number of ticks, max 1 per cell.